# Informix: extractvalue: Extract nth element's attribute value using XPATH

Tags: attributes, extract, informix

I am trying to write an Informix stored procedure that extracts some xml elements values and attribute values using extractvalue function.

How do I extract 2nd person's id using xpath in Informix? I tried the following and its returning null:

```
DROP PROCEDURE sp_parse_xml;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_parse_xml()
RETURNING LVARCHAR(256);

DEFINE l_set SMALLINT;
DEFINE l_node_value LVARCHAR(256);
DEFINE xml_string   LVARCHAR(8000);

LET l_set = 0;

LET xml_string = '<personnel><person id="Jason.Ma"><name><family>Ma</family><given>Jason</given></name></person><person id="12345"><name><family>Smith</family><given>John</given></name></person><person id="67890"><name><family>Cook</family><given>Peter</given></name></person></personnel>';

 LET l_node_value = extractvalue(xml_string, '/personnel/person[2]/@id');
 --RETURN existsnode(xml_string, '/personnel/person[2]/@id');

RETURN l_node_value;

END PROCEDURE;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The expression seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks. I tried evaluating the xpath online and it worked. I am trying to use Informix's extractvalue function that returns a node or an attribute value. This function is similar to Oracle's extractvalue function.

Comment: Apparently Informix `extractvalue` cannot extract attribute values, only element values. If you have a support contract for Informix, open a ticket and ask for a clarification on this issue.

Comment: I tried posting this question on IBM's developer website, but, couldn't. So tried to modify my code and do this and it worked:

Comment: Modified the line:                                                                                                    
           LET l_node_value = extractvalue(xml_string, '/personnel/person[2]/@id'); 
                                                                                                                           
           LET l_node_value = extractvalue(xml_string, '/personnel/person[2]/@id')::LVARCHAR(256);

Comment: I stand corrected; it didn't work. Informix's XML user guide says that the input xml can only have elements, not attributes. I guess this means that XML package cannot parse/extract attribute values.