# Informix XML CLOB extract returning NULL when specifying any @attribute

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, informix, clob

Informix IDS 12.25 is returning NULL whenever an @attribute is specified. In the image below we have the same document being queried by two statements. The difference between the statements is that one of them specifies an @attribute. While the other doesn't. And, as is possible to see in the image, the attribute indeed exists, because it's returned by one of the columns.
[image]

I've been searching a lot, seeing documentations and documentations, all places are saying that the syntax is correct. I don't know what to do anymore.  Really thanks.

[Edit]
Here goes a sample of the xml File I'm working with:

```
<Frame>
<Shape sizeX="5400" sizeY="4400" distance="1800">
  <ShapePoint>
    <Point direction="0" radius="266" />
    <Point direction="144" radius="280" />
    <Point direction="243" radius="289" />
    <Point direction="279" radius="291" />
  </ShapePoint>
</Shape>
</Frame>
```

Alternative approaches for this problem, if mainly using the database engine, also would be extremely welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a valid Xpath, except the first one selects a node, and the one that isn't working selects a string, which makes me think `extractclob()` is having a problem with this type of result.

Here's my test in Python to demonstrate this is the correct xpath for the given xml.

```
In [16]: tree.xpath('/Frame/Shape/ShapePoint/Point[1]')
Out[16]: [<Element Point at 0x102d68bc0>]

In [17]: tree.xpath('/Frame/Shape/ShapePoint/Point[1]/@radius')
Out[17]: ['266']
```

What happens if you use `extractvalueclob()` instead?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.xml.doc/ids_xpextractvalue.htm

Comment: The ending "clob" word just means that the function will return a clob, not that it will read the input as a clob. 
And regarding the "extractvalue" you're right, but it returns null for everything, not only for when specifying an @attribute.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a sample of the XML you're working with?

Comment: Afraid I can't do much more than confirm that is indeed the right xpath for the given XML. Hopefully this leads you in a better direction. Editing the answer to include my test.

Comment: Thanks anyway, once your answer confirmed that the xpath is indeed correct, I upvoted it. But sorry, I can't accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Completely reasonable since it didn't solve the problem. I continued searching and found the comments in this issue, which suggest that `extractvalue()` cannot extract attributes as they are not allowed in the input xml. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150610/informix-extractvalue-extract-nth-elements-attribute-value-using-xpath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230340/discussion-between-forensic-07-and-gabz).